# Can anyone explain the below Code, which is from a GridView_RowDataBound method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

```
Dim tblIdTitleHdr = CType(e.Row.Parent, Table)

tblIdTitleHdr.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * 2 + 1, idTitleHdr)
```

Here, idTitleHdr is a New GridViewRow.

Basically, what this Code does is to repeat a header for each row in a Gridview. The Code's working fine. I just want to know what the above lines of Code do actually. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know what the code does technically (as in, what does CType(...) do?) or do you want to know why someone would write THIS code in order to repeat headers for each row?

Comment: @grek40 I want to know what this Code does technically. Thanks!

Comment: [Ctype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) is converting e.Row.Parent to a table, Tables have an associated ControlCollection to them from what I saw. So [AddAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat?view=netframework-4.7.2) seems to be adding a control to a specified index. Hopefully this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Patrick. What's e.Row.Parent exactly? Thanks!

Comment: I think there's a basic misunderstanding here... Stackoverflow is meant to answer programming related questions but it's not a replacement for documentation reading. Please don't ask for an explanation that can easily be found in the official docs. If you work with the documentation and it is missing / incomplete / wrong, then check if someone else already had the same question. If not, feel free to ask.